# Highlighted current links

Tags: css, wordpress, highlight

I'm working on this Wordpress theme and I'm adding highlighted menus for the current pages using a darker color.
The thing is, I figured out how to highlight the current link, but when I navigate to the "Sample Page" (which is the one who have sub-menus), all the submenus listed get highlited as well. And I don't want that.
The URL -> http://experiencias.freeserver.me/

**The CSS I added:**

```
.nav .current-menu-item a{
    color: #fff;
    background-color:#bc3031;
}
```

**I also tried this to see if it works, but it was not successful**

```
.nav .sub-menu {
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: Define to this   .nav li:hover a{// css code }  not used to this .nav a:hover{}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
.nav .current-menu-item > a{
    color: #fff;
    background-color:#bc3031;
}
```

this will only highlight direct child not nested elements.